# When do we use "wait for" and when we use "wait to"?

Tags: prepositions

According to [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wait?q=WAIT) we normally say: "wait **for**", but sometime we should use the preposition "**to**" with waiting, such as in the following example:

> There were a lot of people **waiting to** use the phone.

Why do we use here "to" rather than "for", or it can be interchangeable?

Comment: Funny, I had thought from your posts that you would know this sort of thing. Please note: wait you=no; and wait to=no. Only wait for a person or thing.

Comment: Thank you. Funny as it is, I'm not a know all. In addition, sometimes it's enough to listen to someone who makes mistake in order to make me not sure about something... Today someone told me that he **waited to** me. I didn't have any proof to say whether he's wrong or correct.

Comment: At your level of English, I wonder why you would doubt yourself. It's pretty basic.

Comment: I can blame myself for that I didn't use Cambridge dictionary that shows prepositions and I was about to close this simple question as you said, but anyway, in retrospect  it shows that there is a case where we use the preposition "to"  "There were a lot of people waiting to use the phone." and it's not clear to me now. I think I'll edit my question based on tat change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just missing the general structure *wait + infinitive*, when talking about waiting to do some action:

> We must **wait to get** on the boat.
>
> Sally **is waiting** until after sunset **to light** the candles.
>
> The horses **waited to enter** the corral.

Otherwise, *for* just expresses the reason for the wait.

> She **is waiting for** the 5:05 train.
>
> I had **to wait** thirty minutes **for** my mother to finish talking to her friends.

Note you can also *wait on* a person

> We're all just **waiting on you** to get ready so we can go.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage is "wait **for** you".

Google has a tool to see which usage is more common; while this doesn't always tell you what is right, it often helps. [For these terms](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wait+to+you%2Cwait+for+you%2C+wait+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwait%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwait%20for%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwait%20you%3B%2Cc0), "wait you" starts out at one-fifth as common as "wait for you" in 1800, but by 2000 it's 3% as common. "Wait to you" is pretty much zero throughout. I think that this is because "wait" used to be used where we now use "await"; now, if you want to omit the "for", you have to say "I **a**wait** you."

Looking through the first few results for "I wait you", the first one is "For you I wait", so that's still "I wait for you", but with different word order. The second one is "I wait, you little ones". So there, "I wait" is a complete clause, and "you" is part of a noun phrase. The third is "I wait. You shout". Again, "wait" and "you" aren't part of the same clause. So it looks like recent uses of "I wait you" are not in fact using "you" as a direct object of "wait".